# Dell raid configuation issue omsa

Tags: raid, storage, dell, dell-openmanage

I've been trying to create a raid using the dell srvadmin tools including raidcfg and omconfig.

Controller info:

```
[root@ksssd tmp]# /opt/dell/toolkit/bin/raidcfg controller controllerid=0
Controller_ID/Slot_ID: 0
Controller_PCI_ID: 1:0:0
  Controller_Name: PERC H310 Mini
         Channels: 2
 No.of Virtual_Disks: 0
      Array_Disks: 0:0:1,0:1:1,0:2:1,0:3:1
 Firmware Version: 20.12.0-0004
```

But, I get this:

```
[root@ksssd tmp]# /opt/dell/toolkit/bin/raidcfg controller action=createvdisk controllerid=0 adisk=0:0:1,0:1:1,0:2:1,0:3:1 -r=5 -ssz=64 -wp=wt -rp=ra -sz=3813376
Limit your array disk selection to those disks already included in another single virtual disk or to those array disks that are not used at all by another virtual disk.
```

I've cleared and reset the controller, even written zeros to the start and end of disks, don't understand what the problem is...

Comment: So, this only seems to affect it when I replace the Dell sata drives with WD sata drives.

Comment: ****** Physical Drive ******
   Vendor: ATA
    Model: WDC WD1003FBYZ-010FB0
 Protocol: SATA 
    Media: HDD
 Location: 0:0:1
     Size: 953344 MB (931 GB)
    Avail: 953344 MB (931 GB)

Comment: can you try with -sz=max ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue, have to first convert disks from "Non-Raid" to "Raid-Capable."

I used the raid config utility at boot to do this step.

At least when Dell ships them they will be in "Raid-Capable" mode, only affects if you replace disks.